# How to do a transition in NUXT waiting the target page to hide the root page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, transition, nuxt.js

I'm building e-commerce and I want to do a transition `Transform: translateY(100%)` when I go to the cart. That is working well, but I need that the first page doesn't disappear until the second page is loaded fully.

There is some way to do the `transitionY` for the new page while the first page (Home for example) is still visible?

```
.enter-active, .leave-active {
    transition: all 1s;
}
.layout-enter, .layout-leave-active {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

Comment: sounds like you are looking for `<transition mode="in-out">`. Docs here have more info: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions#Transition-Modes

Comment: Yes, that is what i need. However, i am not able to do "mode='in-out'" works for layouts. Seems like that is not implemented...